# Response.Filter breaks encoding randomly

Tags: c#, .net, iis, filtering, httpresponse

I have a simple html and javascript client application working with WCF (not an asp.net application). I need to change some variables in my static pages so I tought Response.Filter is the best suitable option for me. I wrote a few line of code and it worked but after I did a few time refresh on my browser, I noticed there was a mistake. Something have broken encoding of the page. What am I doing wrong?

Global.asax: (I tried other events too but nothing changes)

```
private void Application_PostReleaseRequestState(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension.EndsWith(".html") || Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension.EndsWith(".js"))
    {
        Response.Filter = new ContentFilter(Response.Filter);
    }
}
```

ContentFilter.cs

```
public class ContentFilter : MemoryStream
{
    private Stream outputStream = null;

    private Regex version = new Regex("%version%", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);


    public ContentFilter(Stream output)
    {
        outputStream = output;
    }


    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // Convert the content in buffer to a string
        string contentInBuffer = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        contentInBuffer = version.Replace(contentInBuffer, "2");

        outputStream.Write(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contentInBuffer), offset, UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(contentInBuffer));
    }
}
```

[image: chome failure]

Note: I'm using IIS 7.5 on Windows 8.

I saw these while i'm debugging ContentFilter.cs in Write method as the value of contentInBuffer variable. I have GZIP compression by default in IIS settings maybe it's something about that.

`�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0�Z�n�����w3\b(�\"�VD�I���8A۵��a���r�����,m�\t��>@�����t�\n(P�/��+��]���$���B�3s�|���_�n� ...

Comment: Have you checked your response content in Fiddler? I've seen several problems related to Response.Filter but they're mostly related to incorrectly updating the content. I'd first verify headers and the content bytes. Are you using international characters in your response?

Comment: yes there are Turkish chars like ö, ç, ü, ş and ğ. I'll check it with fiddler. I don't understand why but the first time page opens and after 3 times refresh it starts to fail.

Comment: � this is the output from my fiddler. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring the `offset` and `count` that are passed to your `Write` implementation. It might help to use the `GetString` override that also takes an index and a count.

However, I'm afraid there are some other issues. The data you receive in your `Write` function will arrive in chunks. What happens if the first chunk ends with "%vers" and the second starts with "ion%"?

Also, as non-ASCII characters are represented as multiple bytes in UTF-8, a single Unicode character might be "spread across" two subsequent calls to `Write`, which will cause `UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString` to fail.

Comment: I tried to disable IIS Compression, now it works good but it's not a solution. You're right about offset and count. I'm just trying to get it working first. 
I needed this because of cached javascript and css files are causing some issues. Due to my client application is not an ASP.NET aplication, I needed something to invalidate user's browser cache. Do you have any better idea to achieve this?

Comment: @Amount is right - you must buffer your data before you can make changes to it because of the non-ASCII characters in your response.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem, and it was due to GZip compression of static content in IIS.  To combat the corruption, I disabled static compression by the following Web.Config entry:

```
<system.webServer>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

It also turns out files smaller than 2700 bytes are not compressed by default (see the IIS Compression settings) so you'll only see this with static content larger than that.

Hope this helps.